# How to download xml in android project?

Tags: android, xml

Hi i am just a beginner android developer. I just joined Google development console and generated an api key following the steps of which i have no idea how to use it. I completed the book **Android Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide** . 
I am making a project in which the app will download an xml file from server and make a new sql table in the device. I will update only the xml file on server and it will download it and update the table on device. The questions I want to ask are as follows:

1. Is there a way to download xml files from Google development console? Please explain step by step i am just a noob!!!
2. Is this method of conversion xml-->sql table better or should i use only the xml locally as well for retrieving data and displaying?
3. What other servers can be used other than Google? Because there was a chapter in the book which showed how to download thumbnail pictures but from Flickr. I am thinking of the same functionality but only work with text.

Thanks!! waiting for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to get data from xml file, and trying to save it to on sql table which is in device.

1) Apparently its xml parsing you should be using to retrieve the data.

2) you would be using sqlite. There are plenty of tutorial on it already. try checking these things first that would give you a clear idea.

1) xml parsing

2) sqlite in android

Comment: Sir i already know how to parse the data, retrieve it, saving in sql and display it. What i dont know is where to put that xml on internet/google from which i can retrieve it? What is the url to retrieve it? Because the book provides the methods to use from Flickr servive and its api key. I dont know how will it work with google service.

Comment: well you have done most of the work in that case, the XML file you want to retrieve the data from should be on a server. try putting the XML file on your server and the URL will be the absolute directory in which you would keep your XML file

Comment: Where to put it on google development console? Sir please explain this step by step i would really appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Dhruv, are referring to Google developer console or Google development console? kindly try this one https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console

Comment: I am signing for free trial of Google cloud storage. Will it do what I am asking?

Comment: yes but that would be a temporary solution, if you want publish the app in future than having server wouldn't hurt. if you just want to test your code,  you should use localhost than to hustle with cloud storage, that would be a drag